# upgraded org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean : expecting IdClass mapping error

Tags: hibernate, upgrade, legacy, sessionfactory

Hi We upgraded ospring orm from 4.2.9 to 5.0.8 and Hibernate from 5.1.1 to 5.6.15
and still using legacy code (hbm.xml files for mapping and not using annotations,only pojo classes).
Replaced the org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean with
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.

During runtime/deployment of ear file getting following error, your help is appreciated:

Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxSessionFactory' defined in URL [zip:/u01/app/oracle/user_projects/domains/xx/servers/xxx/tmp/_WL_user/pxxi/APP-INF/lib/ps_cc_persistence.jar!/spring/hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expecting IdClass mapping
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:619)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:719)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1929)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3194)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1877)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:932)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)

Spring /hibernate framework upgrade ..hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean4 replaced with hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBeanversion and configuration file is not working.

expecting IdClass mapping